# Using a method to generate multiple instances of another class

Tags: ruby, multiple-instances, instances

I  am trying to let a method initiate multiple instances of another class.

```
class Players
  def initialize(players)
    @players = players
  end
  def generate_boards
    @players.each do |player|
      board = BingoBoardGenerator.new
      player = BingoBoard.new(player, board.generate)
      p player
    end
  end
end

players = ["Nick","Jiyoon","Mae","Lawson","Matthew"]
plays = Players.new(players)
plays.generate_boards
```

`p player` shows that five instances of `BingoBoard` were created properly, but I am not sure how to access them (or where they are). Any help on how to call these instances? Normally I would do:

```
nick = BingoBoard.new("Nick", board.generate) 
nick.board
```

but when I instantiate them all together, I don't know how to set/access their instance name.

Comment: *If* returning an array of boards from "generate boards", then one could use `boards = plays.generate_boards; boards[0].player`, eg. *As it currently is the function returns no useful value.* I would suggest looking into [`Array#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and using it instead of each..

Comment: Thanks, I see what you are saying about setting the variable boards = to the generating boards.  I rearranged my  code a bit and I think I have the right idea now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by user2864740, you can use `:map` instead of `:each` to return an array of `BingoBoard` instances. If you wanted to store those instances to use later, you can use memoization as shown below. The first time `:bingo_board_instances` is called, the boards will be generated and the instance variable `@bingo_board_instances` will be set so that future invocations of `:bingo_board_instances` will not result in the generation of new boards.

```
class Players
  def initialize(players)
    @players = players
  end

  def generate_boards
    @players.map do |player|
      board = BingoBoardGenerator.new
      BingoBoard.new(player, board.generate)
    end
  end

  def bingo_board_instances
    @bingo_board_instances ||= generate_boards
  end
end
```

While the above code works just fine, I think the more intuitive solution would be to have a `Player` class (instead of `Players`) and then pass in an array of `Player` instances when initializing a `BingoBoardGenerator`. With this approach, you can set an instance variable for each individual player and create a unique board that belongs to the player:

```
class BingoBoardGenerator

  def initialize(args)
    #dynamically set instance vars to handle n number of players
    args.fetch(:players).each_with_index do |player,index|
      instance_variable_set("@player_#{index+1}",player)
    end
  end

  def generate_boards
    instance_variables.map do |player|
      player = instance_variable_get(instance_var)
      #you will need to implement :generate_bingo_board on player...I would suggest using memoization so you can store the player's board for later retrieval
      player.generate_bingo_board
    end
  end
end

#I have no idea what your implementation looks like...
b = BingoBoardGenerator.new(players: [Player.new("Jen"),Player.new("Phil"),Player.new("Mary"),Player.new("Bert")])

b.generate_boards
```

This would allow you to better encapsulate data that may belong to individual players, including the ability to ask each `Player` instance for its `:board`.